# Shell script to remove everything in line after second comma and write to file?

Tags: regex, csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Wave 1,bob,IL
Wave 2,julia,CO
Wave 1,mark,WA
Wave 2,fred,AK
```

I want to change it to look like this:

```
Wave 1,bob
Wave 2,julia
Wave 1,mark
Wave 2,fred
```

I can use use `cut -d ',' -f 1-2 test.csv` to produce this result in stdout but I need to output to the same file being cut. I have tried `cut -d ',' -f 1-2 test.csv > test.csv` and `stdbuf -o0 cut -d ',' -f 1-2 test.csv > test.csv` but they both produce blank test.csv files.

How can I remove everything after the second comma on a per line basis, and write the result in-place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed command find and replace in file and overwrite file doesn't work, it empties the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties)

Comment: Off the beaten path, you could use [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sponge.1.html) to write to the input file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as real "inplace" editing with any UNIX tool*, they all use tmp files behind the scenes. Keep it simple:

```
cut -f1,2 file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

*exceptions: `ed` uses an internal buffer the size of the original file instead of a tmp file and `dd` CAN be used to do inplace editing but is not for the faint of heart (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001).

Answer (score 2):

If you have `gnu awk` 4.1.0+ then it has support of in place editing using `-i inplace` option:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $2}' file

cat file
Wave 1,bob
Wave 2,julia
Wave 1,mark
Wave 2,fred
```

Comment: And if you're on something else than GNU awk 4.1.0+ , see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/4162356).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, this is how can be done with cut that you have been trying to:

```
cut -d, -f1-2 <<<"$(<file1)" >file1
```

Or

```
cut -d, -f1-2 file1 |tee file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/,..$/,"")}1' file

Wave 1,bob
Wave 2,julia
Wave 1,mark
Wave 2,fred
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/,/\n/2;P;d' file
```

1.
replace the 2th "," as "\n"

2.
use P to print up to the 1th "\n"

3.
delete the pattern space