# Is it possible to add some text at beginning of a file in CLI without making new file?

Tags: awk, sed, text-editor, text-formatting

I have two files `file1` containing -

```
hello world
hello bangladesh
```

and `file2` containing -

```
Dhaka in Bangladesh
Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh
```

I want to new `file2` as -

```
hello world
hello bangladesh 
Dhaka in Bangladesh
Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh
```

This is done by -

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
mv file3 file2
```

But, I don't want to create new file. I guess using `sed` it may be possible.

Comment: Simply write `cat file1 file2 >> file2`? works fine for me on my console

Comment: @SourceOverflow: Are you sure about that? I got an error message "`cat: file2: input file is output file`". Perhaps you meant to write `cat file1 >> file2` -- but that would append the content of `file1` to the end of `file2`. The OP wants to insert the content of `file1` at the top of `file2`.

Comment: @KeithThompson nope I did it exactly as I described. I got the 'error' (warning?) too, but it still worked. I can't guarantee that that is always the case for every interpreter and that there are no race conditions (which is why I just posted a comment)

Comment: @SourceOverflow: Sorry, when I saw the error message I didn't bother to check the file contents. But when I ran the command on my system (using bash 4.4.0), the lines in `file2` were in the wrong order. (My head hurts trying to figure out just what happened.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Probably some sort of race condition? idk to be honest :/

Comment: @SourceOverflow Then if people can confused viewing your 1st comment.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

```
printf '%s\n' '0r file1' x | ex file2
```

This is a POSIX-compliant command using [`ex`, the POSIX-specified non-visual predecessor to `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

`printf` is only used here to feed a command to the editor.  What `printf` outputs is:

```
0r file1
x
```

`x` is save and exit.

`r` is "read in the contents of the named file."

`0` specifies the line number after which the read-in text should be placed.

N.B. This answer is fully copied from [Is it possible to add some text at beginning of a file in CLI without making new file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070023/is-it-possible-to-add-some-text-at-beginning-of-a-file-in-cli-without-making-new/48070123#48070123)

**Another solution**
There aren't a lot of ways to modify files in place using standard tools. Even if they appear to do so they may be using temporary files (i.e. GNU `sed -i`).

`ex` on the other hand, will do the trick:

```
ex +'0r file2' +wq file1
```

`ex` is a line editor and `vim` evolved from it so these commands may look familiar. `0r filename` does the same thing as `:0r filename` in `vim`: insert the specified file after the given address (line number). The line number here is 0 which is a kind of virtual line that represents the line before line 1. So the file will be inserted before any existing text.

Then we have `wq` which saves and quits.

That's it.

N.B. This answer is fully copied from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414408/176227

Comment: Nice. I would have expected `ex` to create a new file, but (at least on my system, with the `ex` provided by Vim 8.0) it overwrites the original file, leaving it with the same inode number. Doing the equivalent with `vim` creates a new file.

Comment: `ex` creates an internal buffer the size of the input file so if you're trying to avoid creating a temp file for memory reasons then YMMV! You can do the same thing with awk by reading all of the input into an array, closing the input file, then writing it back out in the END section. I expect GNU sed at least has some combination of runes that'd let it do the same. The way to do it without buffering the whole file is described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert two lines at the top of an existing file.

There's no general way to do that. You can append data to the end of an existing file, but there's no way to insert data other than at the end, at least not without rewriting the portion of the file after the insertion point.

Once a file has been created, you can overwrite data within it, but the position of any unmodified data remains the same.

When you use a text editor to edit a file, it performs the updates in memory; when you save the file, it may create a new file with the same name as the old one, or it may create a temporary file and then rename it. either way, it has to write the entire content, and the original file will be clobbered (though some editors may create a backup copy).

Your method:

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
mv file3 file2
```

is pretty much the way to do it (except that the `>>` should be `>`; you don't want to retain the previous contents of `file3` if it already exists).

You can use a temporary file name:

```
cat file1 file2 > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ file2
```

`tmp$$` uses the current shell's process ID to generate a file name that's almost certain to be unique (so you don't clobber anything). The `&&` means that the `mv` command won't be executed if the `cat` command failed, so that you'll still have the original `file2` if there was an error.