# Effective way to delete first N lines of a large 100M-line file in linux shell

Tags: shell

Suppose that I have a large text file with `100M` lines; What is the most effective way to delete first N lines of it, such as `50M` lines.

As I tried, only opening this file with vim will take several minutes.

Are there any more effective ways to accomplish this?

Comment: If you know which lines you want to preserve, why not just copy those out of the file into a new file, then delete the original?

Comment: @GovindParmar This way is fine. I wonder how to do this without opening the large file with vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tail -n +50000000 file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If you don't have the storage to almost duplicate the input file then to edit it truly in place (i.e. not using a temp file like all of the command line "inplace" editing tools like `sed`, `perl`, etc. use, nor a buffer the size of your input file like `ed` uses) you could do:

```
bytes=$(head -50000000 file |wc -c)
dd if=file bs="$bytes" skip=1 conv=notrunc of=file
truncate -s "-$bytes" file
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001 for more info on that last script.