# extracting last n percentage of a file output from zcat command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, wc

I am trying to extract the last 2 percentage of a file output coming from the zcat command. I tried something doing

```
numlines=$(zcat file.tar.gz | wc -l)
zcat file.tar.gz | tail -n + $numlines*(98/100)
```

But the problem with this approach is my file is too big, and I can't afford to run the zcat command twice. Is there some way I could do it by maybe piping the number of lines , or some other ways.

EDIT :
The output of `zcat file.tar.gz | tar -xO | dd 2>&1 | tail -n 1` is

16942224047 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 109.154 s, 155 MB/s

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The last 2% of a tar file? But that means you're not going to be able to use it with tar as it's not a complete archive...

Comment: If decompression speed is an issue, consider using zstd instead of gzip.

Comment: Please add output of `zcat file.tar.gz | tar -xO | dd 2>&1 | tail -n 1` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I added it , please take a look .

Comment: @Shawn, I am referring to  the last 2 % of the contents of a tar file . I can't decompress the file , so I'm using zcat just to read the content

Comment: But the last X% of a tar archive can be a partial file, or part of one file and 1 or more other files... In the latter case discarding everything before the first complete file header would work for turning it into a usable archive. But your goal doesn't really make sense. And what do you think zcat does if not decompress?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331179/1745001. Good luck!

Comment: @PujanPaudel `and I can't afford to run the zcat command twice` You have to. Like, it's impossible to calculate size of a part of a cake now knowing the size of the whole cake. You have to know how many lines you have to calculate 2% of the lines. You could assume that 2% is at least <enter number> lines and buffer that many while calculating count of lines, but if that's number is too small you will have to re-run zcat anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Read content to a variable. I assume that there is enough RAM available.

```
content=$(zcat file.tar.gz| tar -xO)
lines=$(wc -l <<<"$content")
ninetyeight=$((100-$lines/100*98))
tail -n $ninetyeight
```

This only works if the file contains at least 100 lines.

Comment: I have pretty good amount of RAM In my system , but I got xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes. I guess the file is just too big , aren't there any non memory consuming idas

Answer (score 2):

The following awk program will only keep the last *n*% of your file into memory. The percentage is taken floor wise, that is to say, if we *n*% of the file represents 134.56 lines, it will print 134 lines

```
awk -v n=2 '{a[FNR]=$0; min=FNR-int(FNR*n/100)}
            {i=min; while(i in a) delete a[i--]}
            END{for(i=min+1;i<=FNR;++i) print a[i]}' - < <(zcat file)
```

you can verify this when you replace `zcat file` with `seq 100`